# Having trouble installing gem "termios" after trying to update Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am attempting to update Rails from 3.1.3 to 3.2.8. Changing the rails gem value and running "bundle update rails" tries to install a gem called "termios" version 0.9.4, and this fails with the following message:

```
Installing termios (0.9.4) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling termios.c
In file included from termios.c:10:
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2:     warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
termios.c: In function ‘Termios_to_termios’:
termios.c:182: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
termios.c:183: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
termios.c: In function ‘termios_tcgetattr’:
termios.c:200: error: ‘OpenFile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [termios.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/termios-0.9.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@mcp5/gems/termios-0.9.4/./gem_make.out
An error occured while installing termios (0.9.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install termios -v '0.9.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Please note also that this is the first time that I have updated Rails since I have gone to OS X Mountain Lion.

I have seen another answer about this question that said to install a gem called "ruby-termios". I did that, and that gem installed fine, but there is still a dependency somewhere that tries to install the "termios" gem.

Comment: were you able to run rails at all after upgrading to mountain lion?

Comment: Yes. I had to reinstall gcc and a do a few other mods. Was using rvm, also had to reinstall ruby 1.9.3. Then used brew to reinstall ImageMagick.

Comment: well just doing that solved the make poblems for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that specifying `gem 'engineyard'` in your Gemfile will cause bundler to install some ancient version (0.2.x), which has the termios dependency.

Specifying a newer one (`gem 'engineyard', '~> 2.3'`) will install correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up cloning the [ruby-termios](https://github.com/arika/ruby-termios) gem into my repo. For some unknown reason, the author named it ruby-termios instead of just termios. So I renamed the gemspec. Then I modified my Gemfile to use:

```
gem 'termios', :path => 'termios'
```

Then I ran:

```
bundle update
```

And everything is working again.

Comment: I followed your tip. So it can be: `gem 'termios', git: 'git://github.com/edison/ruby-termios.git'` too.

Comment: Awesome. I have not smart enough to have thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

`gem install ruby-termios` solved the make issues for me; I expect `gem "ruby-termios"` in your Gemfile will work too.

Looks like what happened is that the original author of the gem named `termios` (arika) hasn't updated the gem since 2004 (v 0.9.4), but nobody owns the namespace on rubygems http://rubygems.org/gems/termios. Then someone else (edison) made a fork on github https://github.com/edison/ruby-termios, and someone *else* (tylerrick) pushed a new gem named `ruby-termios`... but of course inside Ruby, the library is still named `termios` so the command is still `require "termios"`.